# My firebase cloud functions link is not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My cloud functions API link is not working even though it's deployed successfully. When I open it, it shows like:

**Error:Forbidden**

**Your client does not have permission to get URL /api from this server.**

[Screenshot of the API site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBaWC.png)

Can anyone help me out pls

firebase version: 8.9.0

firebase functions: 3.15.7

Comment: No, I already have the owner role, which should give me access to everything

Comment: You do have access to everything, but functions by default are not publicly available even to you and you must specifically make them publicly available to a web browser if that's your goal. The function doesn't know it's you trying to access it from a browser. Check the issue I linked to.